# Rails model how to create an array based on last value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I have:

```
attr_accessor :ppris

def last(x)
    @ppris = []

    if @ppris == nil
        @ppris << 1
    else
        @ppris << 2
    end
end

def pakke
  if self.pakkes.count > 0
  self.pakkes.each{|pakke| beregn_pakke(pakke.price)}
  end
end
```

In view a have a normal loop for my Company model.

```
<%= company.ppris %>
```

In view the value for ppris is `[2]` for all rows.

I have 5 Company rows in my table. I would expect that the value for ppris would be:
`[1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` for each company.

I have also changed the model method to:

```
def last(x)
@ppris = []
if @ppris == nil
@ppris << 1
else
@ppris << @ppris.last + 1
end
end
```

But then I get a NoMethodError. I would expect no error an ppris be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What is wrong with my model method? Why can't I create an array that gets added values for each pakke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ppris = []
if @ppris == nil
```

`@ppris` will never be `nil`. It'll be `empty?`, but not `nil`.

*Addressing your comment*

You create a new array every time you call the method. If you want a single array associated with an instance, create one in the [`after_initialize` callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find).

Comment: I have changed that but still company.ppris is only [1] for each company I would expect it to be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @Railsbeginner Because you create a new `@ppris` every time you call the method.

Comment: How do I then not create a new '@ppris' every time? Can I create a method wish not creates a new '@ppris' every time?

Comment: I have managed to find out how. Just offcourse removed the @ppris = []
 and replaced the if @ppris.empty? with if @ppris.nil?

Comment: @Railsbeginner As long as you can handle the `nil` if the method isn't called, I guess that solution is okay--I'd rather see it initialized, though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
def last(x)
  @ppris = []
  if @ppris.empty?
    @ppris << 1
  else
    @ppris << @ppris.last + 1
  end
end
```